# C# Overloading of methods with params modifier

Tags: c#, parameters, mono, overloading

I have 2 methods as follows

```
int foo (int a, param int[] b);  // f1
int foo (params int[] a);        // f2
```

**In expanded form how can I ever call `f1`?**

**Info**:

When I use the *expanded form* `foo (1, 2)` this calls `f2`. I need to explicitly use the *normal form* `foo (1, new [] {2})` to call `f1`

I am using `Mono C# compiler version 4.6.2.0` - https://repl.it/Fy4L

Comment: It is already calling `f1`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/4o33kC

Comment: foo(1,new int[]{2}); Using this syntax you can call function1 , otherwise function 2 will be called.

Comment: Even [TryRoslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmSZGAMwD2gmAApeMKgBoOVAE5V0dXgG0AujAIBKZq3b76giCEFFUAOgDqcsGgAykVKIBE/AIzOtOffrmpkwHIQMG7e7AC+APSRAm7YAJCcJOQSQiKiuPKKyhDI6pI6LD7shsamFta2qA4QTq4ATJ5hxX4BQTD1zTDhemxJ3ABugmAAJjAAsqKFvT5pom4ADDL1C14zPeFAA==) says the same (look on the right pane how the call is translated by the compiler)

Comment: From memory the overload resolution considers things that put as few things into the params as possible as better matches. I forget the exact rules but I am pretty sure that this will call f1 in preference to f2 if you pass multiple ints and indeed experimentation backs this up. Can you explain exactly when you would expect it to call f2? The only time I can think it would is if you called `foo()` but in that case you'd be better off just having a parameterless overload...

Comment: I'm voting to close this until you can provide code that actually recreates your problem.

Comment: @xanatos I am using mono and it is consistent to the question: https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-c-sharp-online . This might be one of those compiler dependent issues. Is there a spec for such a thing?

Comment: please add your real code, or a really close implementation. From what I can see now, it's f1 that'll be called always, no matter what.

Comment: @LibinVarghese Yes, you are right, that version of mono has a problem... There was at least a bug about params in mono: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19754 I don't know if it was the same bug or another bug. Use newer mono.

Comment: @Chris - the only way, for .NET now (tested on 4.5 and 4.6) - to call f2 is to call `foo(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });` -- all others will always call f1. 
What it's doing on MONO, well, my guess.. That's why MONO up until now is so unreliable in my point. But it would be useful to have a real world example of his code. Check: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pkPNgZ

Comment: @LibinVarghese Found... Exactly the same bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6541 The test code uses `string` instead of `int`.

Comment: @xanatos: Added that link into my answer. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Why would anyone use mono now that .net core is available on Linux and Mac?  Assuming you're not trying to do desktop development for Linux, which most .net code on Linux is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the language spec for C#5 found at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029 we find the following:

> "if MP has more declared parameters than MQ, then MP is better than
>   MQ. This can occur if both methods have params arrays and are
>   applicable only in their expanded forms"

-Section 7.5.3.2

MQ and MP are referring to the candidate methods in the overload resolution. Expanded form refers to the params array being expanded to a sequence of parameters (ie when the params part is being utilised).

What this means is that in this version of the spec if you have more declared parameters (which f1 does) then it will be the better candidate.

From memory this has always been the case though I have not checked all versions of the spec. Changing this behaviour at any point would be a breaking change which I would be 99.99% certain the compiler team would not have done (thanks to @xanatos for pointing this out in comments). I believe that the answer then is that in your code it should be choosing f1 as the correct overload and a bug in mono is causing the behaviour you are seeing.

This seems to be supported by https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6541 which @xanatos found (thanks again). The bug sample code uses strings but is the same issue.

Comment: *From memory this has always been the case* changing it would have been a breaking change in the compiler, something that is rarely done.

Comment: @xanatos: Very true. Have added that to my answer to make it clearer. I didn't like to say for definite though given I haven't *actually* checked all the specs. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int f(int i, params int[] a) { return 1; }  // 1
int f(       params int[] a) { return 2; }  // 2
```

Then you can do few tests:

```
Debug.Print("" + f(1)               );      // 1
Debug.Print("" + f(1, 2)            );      // 1 (2 in Mono?)
Debug.Print("" + f(1, new int[] { }));      // 1

Debug.Print("" + f()                    );  // 2
Debug.Print("" + f(new int[] { } )      );  // 2
Debug.Print("" + f(new int[] { 1, 2 })  );  // 2
```