Are there ambiguities between constructor (object, params ICommand[]) and constructor (params ICommand[])?
I have a class CompositeCommand, with the following (overloaded) constructors:
public class CompositeCommand:ICommandToolTip
{

    public CompositeCommand(params ICommand[] commands):this(null, commands)
    {

    }
    public CompositeCommand(object toolTip, params ICommand[] commands)
    {
        ToolTip = toolTip;
        _commands = commands.ToArray();
    }
}

It seems that for now, when I call CompositeCommand(ACommand aaa, BCommand bbb) ( where ACommand and BCommand are inheriting from ICommand) , the second constructor will be called correctly. But this is a behavior I can count on? And super crucially, is this documented in the C# spec?

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42471077/5133585 The quote from the spec is now worded as "if both methods have params arrays and are applicable only in their expanded forms, and if the params array of Mᵢ has fewer elements than the params array of Mₑ, then Mᵢ is better than Mₑ" which is basically the same thing. Link to spec

As far as I know, constructor overload resolution adheres to the same overload resolution rules of any other methods - which means that the answer to both your questions is yes.
The Overload resolution section in the c# language specification documents the rules by which a specific overload is chosen.
In the process of overload resolution, the best suited overload is chosen by the c# compiler (if there isn't a singe best overload, you'll get a binding-time error).
In your case, you have one constructor containing types that are more specific than the other constructor, the better overload is the one with more specific types.1
1 There are exceptions to this rule such as virtual methods and such, but they do not apply here.

The parameter type accepted by the constructor is ICommand, and the type passed in is ACommand. I don't think this can be considered exact. An object of type ACommand can be implicitly converted to either ICommand or object, and this can also be applied to null.

@shingo Good point, however I suppose that a better implicit conversion would be to the more specific form, meaning ICommand in this case. A careful read of the overload resolution documentation would probably find the exact spot where it's explained.

A constructor can call an overloaded constructor in the same object by using the this keyword. You can see examples in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors.
This is called a constructor chaining technique and you can find some examples here: https://www.greetreads.com/csharp/csharp-constructor-chaining-and-example

That's not the point of this question. It's about which one will be chosen to be called under various circumstances.

You are missing the point, though.
